# getting just the sign of the result from a dot product

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm implementing a `dot` unit in an electrical design, but I'm only interested in the sign of the result and not the magnitude. Is there a way to reduce the number of mathematical operations (mainly the multiplication operations) to get just the sign faster and with less space?

Right now I'm calculating it using: `(a1,b1,c1).(a2,b2,c2)=a1.a2+b1.b2+c1.c2`.

Comment: Anything special about your vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

Compare

```
(10,20,29).(40,10,-20) = +20  
(10,20,30).(40,10,-20) = 0  
(10,20,31).(40,10,-20) = -20
```

and there are no obvious shortcuts to find the signs.